# Converting an object to a set of variables

Tags: php, variables

How would you go about converting:

```
$Object->one;
$Object->two;
```

to:

```
$one;
$two;
```

Comment: Consider that you may be violating the encapsulation of the object (which should not expose its members)

Comment: @alcuadrado: That's a good note. I'll have that in mind.

Comment: If they are public, then they are already exposed. Thus leading to you doing odd things like this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it into an array then `extract()` it.

Keep alcuadrado's comment in mind regarding encapsulation; it's emphasized by the fact that `extract()` will only work on public instance variables (I've updated my example code to show this).

```
class TestClass
{
    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;
    private $three = 3;
}

$object = new TestClass;
extract((array) $object);

var_dump($one, $two, $three);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: third in...
int(1)
int(2)
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a foreach loop on an object, it will iterate over the visible properties without exposing private members.

```
foreach ($object as $key => $value){
  $$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: `extract(get_object_vars($Object));`

That will only get the public variables. If you want private, then you'd need to call it from within the object itself.